# Invalid Image Path - No image found

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, app-store

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to upload my project into AppStore.

#### frist issue

> Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'icon-76'

#### second issue

> your binary is not optimised for iPhone - 5 - new iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image with the -568h size modifier immediately following th  portion of the launch image's filename. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .Iproj folder if you localise your launch images. Learn more about iPhone 5 support and app launch images by reviewing the 'iOS Human interface guidelines' at 'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/mobileHIG/Iconimages/IconImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14_SW5' and the 'IOS App Programming Guide' at 'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResorces.html#//apple_ref.doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12

Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: what is your question? everything was clearly phrased on the screenshot you attached. you have to solve those issues, **(1)** adding the missing icon, **(2)** supporting iPhone5 screen size – link for guidelines attached to the error message.

Comment: maybe you haven't included app icon for and splash screen and images for iphone 5. your app is compatible for iphone 5?

Comment: My eyes are too old, and I can't read that even with my glasses. Perhaps you should add the error to the question in text format. Text format will also allow future visitors to search for it.

Comment: @jww: I have edited his question :)

Comment: @jww, you can open the image separately and you can zoom in. :)

Comment: There is no missing icons and no CFBundleIcons in my plist. But the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Supporting Files -> yourproject-info.plist file, under the Icon Files -> click the down arrows** and cross check the icon names and bundle icon file names.

Adding the required images and Removing the unwanted ones from your project and info.plist will easily fix this issue.

If the image exists, make sure that this image is a members of target you are building.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have faced the same issue and found the solution by adding the default-568h@2x.png file at the root level As show in the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue.I don't think you answered the question correctly.

- I'm using Images.xcassets for the AppIcon. All the sizes are included. Even the one reported missing. And there is no CFBundleIcons in my Info.plist.
- I even don't use Launch images in my project. Instead I'm using LaunchScreen.xib file as the launch screen.